# Button in container view not working

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I built in a segmented control in Swift 4 using the TwicketSegmentedControl-Framework ([find it here on GitHub](https://github.com/twicketapp/TwicketSegmentedControl)). 
My storyboard looks like this:

[image]

I added three container views – home, profile and settings –, each with a corresponding VC.swift-file, which are switched through by the segmented control. This is working well, however, any buttons implemented in one of the three views won't work, can't be pressed even.

Do you have a clue why that might be?

My ViewController.swift-file, in which the segmented control sits looks like this:
[ViewController.swift on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/janninho/b9fd322055c2c8619e3a8a3774d30762).

I included a button in the first view, "HOME", created an outlet in the corresponding HomeVC.swift-file.

Comment: Check if user interaction is enable or not for that controller and button.

Comment: @ChaiBiskut this is what I thought about at first as well – it is.

Comment: You have used container view right?

Comment: Yes, I did use container views.

Comment: Not able to detect much from this.. Need to see thoroughly.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved!?

Answer (score 1):

You can use observer pattern here
in button Action put the below code

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "callForAlert"), object: nil)
```

In your VC.swift in viewDidLoad() method put below code

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(hideContainerView), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "callForAlert"), object: nil)
```

Where hideContainerView is the function which I have created for hiding the container view

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: You can find an example on below link
https://medium.com/@apmason/using-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift-3-f88b88379986